# If $\|u\|=2, \|v\|=2$ and $u⋅v=3$, find $\|u+2v\|$

Tags: vectors

If $\|u\|=2, \|v\|=2$ and $u⋅v=3$, find $\|u+2v\|$, give your answer in $2$ decimal places.
I can't seem to find $\|u+2v\|$ no matter what I do.

Comment: Can you show $\|u+2v\|^2=\|u\|^2+4u\cdot v+4\|v\|^2$?

Comment: "no matter what I do", sometimes just writing the definition is already half way to the solution...